# Completely disable IPTables

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, nftables

I have been playing around with switching to nftables (purely as a learning exercise). I have it all working perfectly except for the fact I have to manually unload iptable_nat from the kernel after a restart.

What I have attempted so far

- completely flushed the iptables rules
- rmmod everything to do with Xtables
- blacklist all Xtables modules

None of these stop iptable_nat from loading on reboot and this stops nf_nat from working. Once I have run rmmod iptable_nat it works as expected.

Does anyone know how to completely disable IPTables on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?